# "Dereferencing pointer to incomplete type", typedefs are ok

Tags: c, struct, types, dereference

I'm trying to implement a hash table. I get the above error but AFAIK I've properly declared all my structs/typedefs. (I'm still learning C, sorry)
The error occurs in test.c in my while loop, where I've put //ERROR. What's wrong?

test.c

```
#include "mentry.h"
#include "mlist.h"

int main() {
  FILE *fPtr = fopen("S.txt", "r");
  MList *ml = ml_create();

  MEntry *m2;
  int i = 1;
  while ((m2 = me_get(fPtr)) != NULL) {
    unsigned long int hash = me_hash(m2, ml->numbuckets); // ERROR HERE
    i++;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

mlist.c

```
#include "mentry.h"
#include "mlist.h"

#define NUMBUCKETS 3
#define BUCKETSIZE 5

typedef struct bucket {
  int size; // number of elements in this bucket
  MEntry *entries; // array of MEntries
} Bucket;

typedef struct mlist {
  int numbuckets; // number of buckets
  Bucket **buckets; // an array of Bucket pointers
} MList;

/* ml_create  - creates a new mailing list
              - returns pointer to start of mailing list*/
MList *ml_create(void) {
  MList *ml = malloc(sizeof(MList));

  ml->numbuckets = NUMBUCKETS; // random initial number
                               // will increment once a bucket is full

  // init Buckets
  int b;
  for (b=0; b<ml->numbuckets; b++) {
    Bucket *bk = malloc(sizeof(Bucket));
    bk->size = 0;
    bk->entries = calloc(BUCKETSIZE, sizeof(MEntry));
    ml->buckets[b] = bk;
  }

  return ml;
}
```

mlist.h

```
#ifndef _MLIST_H_
#define _MLIST_H_

#include "mentry.h"

typedef struct mlist MList;

/* ml_create  - creates a new mailing list
              - returns pointer to start of mailing list*/
MList *ml_create(void);

#endif /* _MLIST_H_ */
```

Comment: In `test.c` there is no visible definition of `numbuckets`. You need to move the struct definitions from `mlist.c` into a header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time you attempt to access `ml->numbuckets` in `main`, all it knows about the type of `m1` is this:

```
typedef struct mlist MList;
```

It knows that `MList` is a structure type, but it knows nothing about what's in it.

You need to put the full definition in `mlist.h`:

```
#ifndef _MLIST_H_
#define _MLIST_H_

#include "mentry.h"

typedef struct mlist {
  int numbuckets; // number of buckets
  Bucket **buckets; // an array of Bucket pointers
} MList;

/* ml_create  - creates a new mailing list
              - returns pointer to start of mailing list*/
MList *ml_create(void);

#endif /* _MLIST_H_ */
```

Answer (score 1):

> What's wrong?

You can use `ml->numbuckets` only if the complete definition of `MList` is visible at that line.

Since the complete definition of `MList` is visible only in mlist.c, you can access the members of the `struct` only in that file.

One way to do this would be to declare a function in mlist.h:

```
unsigned long int me_hash_list(MEntry* m1, MList* m2);
```

and define it in mlist.c as:

```
unsigned long int me_hash_list(MEntry* m1, MList* m2)
{
   return me_hash(m1, m2->numbuckets);
}
```

and then call `me_hash_list` from `main`.

```
while ((m2 = me_get(fPtr)) != NULL) {
  unsigned long int hash = me_hash_list(m2, ml);
  i++;
}
```